# Releasing .exe file from input string as code

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, csc

I have a question. How to release `.exe` file from `string input`?

I want to compile to `exe` [Hello World](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/hello-world-your-first-program) `C#` example. Here is my code:

```
var code = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
string exeName = string.Format("test.exe", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
var parameters = new CompilerParameters
{
    GenerateExecutable = true,
    OutputAssembly = exeName,
    GenerateInMemory = false,
    TreatWarningsAsErrors = false
};
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

var compilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

if (compilerResults.Errors.Count > 0)
    //Error

else
    //Succes, file saved int Debug folder (exe file)
```

From code above, i want to get `code` as `string`, then i make `string[]` array (each array's record is next line of code). Then, i want to save that `exe` file into `Debug` Folder.

But for, now, from `compilerResults.Errors` i get `32` errors that looks like this:

[image]

I belive that is something about mapping this function to `c#` language. Any ideas, what im doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

`code` array looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like `input` isn't correct. Please show how you're creating that, or show a screenshot of what the value looks like.

Comment: I shared `code` array from my debugging process in Edit @JonSkeet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CodeDomProvider.CreateAssemblyFromSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) expects each string in the array to be a source *file* - you're providing a single *line* per element.

In other words, you don't need your call to `Split` to start with. Just use:

```
var code = new[] { input };
```

Comment: Now i get `{error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\test.exe' for writing` error, could you tell me, why this is happening? My app is `ASP MVC`, i want to save that `.exe` in debug folder

Comment: @michasaucer: Well you're trying to write it to the current working directory - you'll need to find the right folder to store it in, and specify that explicitly. Note that `string.Format("test.exe", Environment.CurrentDirectory)` almost certainly doesn't do what you expect; I suspect you wanted `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.exe")` but that will still use the current directory...